# google app engine Error reporting does not work

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php, google-cloud-error-reporting

the last week my php flex app on app-engine has been causing error 500, sometimes. I dont have changed nothing in my code. But the strangest is that nothing is shown in the error reporting panel. Someone knows if there are new updates or something like that for App Engine?.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The last change on December 9, 2019 is about:

App Engine is changing the URLs that you use to send requests to your apps. You can now include a region ID to help Google route your requests more efficiently and reliably. For example, an app can receive requests at https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com. This new URL is optional for existing apps, and will soon be required for all new apps

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/release-notes

Maybe this could be causing some internal erros. It would be nice more details bout the 500s errors.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. in the last 30 days there are nothing of  logs in error reporting panel.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the error logs of my app, they are in [Stackdriver Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs). And not in the [Error Reporting Panel](https://console.cloud.google.com/errors)

Blessings.